# Defer touch events to widget under in Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to recreate a UI navigation like [this](https://gfycat.com/likableamusingjanenschia)

To do that, I have a `Stack` with my map in the background and a `PageView` on top with the middle page set to be empty and `HitTestBehavior.translucent` to let the touch events be handled by the map under.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("button pressed");
              },
              child: Text("Press me"),
            ),
          )),
      PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ]));
```

However, this doesn't seems to work, here the button under the pageview cannot be touched even when the pageview in on the middle page.

Any ideas? And is this even the right way to approach that problem?

Comment: The image link appears to be broken.

Comment: That `GestureDetector` isn't producing any effect as it is, actually. You'd be fine by just removing it from the `PageView` children.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo but then I would only have 2 pages, I still want to access the screen under in the stack